# Variance of $k$th order statistic of normal vector

Tags: asymptotics, order-statistics, extreme-value

Let $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$. Let $Z_{(k)}$ be the $k$th order statistic of $Z$.

1. Is it true that $\text{Var}(Z_{(k)}) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$?
2. Any estimate on the rate?

What about for some more general $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$?

Comment: @Xi'an Almost. Checking the references in the answer, I cant see a way to bound the remainder terms in the expansion.

Comment: Can anyone explain how the linked "duplicate" answers my question? The link provides an estimate on the variance based on a Taylor expansion, ignoring the higher order terms. It's clear that the truncated version is asymptotically zero, but the contribution of the higher order terms is completely ignored.